# Audio playing even though video (and its container) are set to "display: none;"

Tags: angularjs, audio, ionic3, brightcove

I have a Brightcove video that is set to autoplay with sound, but ONLY when the page is viewed on a mobile device. I set a media query to have the video and it's containers set to "display: none" when it's on desktop. However, the audio still plays on desktop. How can I turn this off?

Is this possible to do with just CSS, ideally without messing with the player itself or adding Javascript?

Comment: It's not. CSS justs affects the visibility, the player elements are still present.

Comment: You must use Javascript for this. CSS doesn't have such capabilities. You can either remove the whole element if it is added programatically after an event of select the video element and pause it.

Answer (score 0):

display:none does not actually remove the item from the DOM. It is still present, just not visible. Any other CSS option will achieve the same end result. If you do not want the player, you will have to make changes in the code to remove it from the DOM.